# how to isolate constructor parameters when writing custom ESlint rule for Typescript

Tags: typescript, eslint, customization, abstract-syntax-tree

My goal is to alphabetically sort the constructor parameters using "quick fix" from eslint (I'm trying to write this custom rule in order to do that)

and for now I just want to 'isolate' the constructor parameters and have eslint display squiggly lines and my `message` when I hover over them, but I don't know how to get that by just looking at an AST of this example code here:
https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/dc0def03c26658b1bfa5d8743f9a9f91/70365c30bee24bbec8289744ef4d33cf42268cb8

Which one do I choose? and how do I make sure it only checks ones in the constructor?

```
//example code used in AST explorer      
constructor(
        private _appService: AppService,
        private _authService: AuthService,
        private _formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private _manageScenarioService: ManageScenarioService,
      ) {}
```

**this is what I have so far:** the problem with this is it highlights all identifiers, and not just the ones within the consturctor

```
 import { Rule } from 'eslint';
    export function diSortRule(context: Rule.RuleContext): Rule.RuleListener {
      return {
        Identifier(node) {
          context.report({
            node,
            message: 'this pops up here',
          });
        },
      };
    }
```

any help would be so appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

I know it is long time ago already but I hope it can still come handy to you or others. We just published a rule which is autofixable and it sorts constructor parameters in classes decorated by one of `@Component()`, `@Directive()`, `@Injectable()`, `@Pipe()`.

You can use it as:

1. install our plugin: `npm install --save-dev @erento/eslint-plugin-erento-rules`
2. Add this to your .eslintrc

   ```
   "plugins": [
       "@erento/erento-rules"
   ],
   "rules": {
       "@erento/erento-rules/injectable-order": "error"
   }
   ```
3. run your ESLint linter

More to this rule is here:
https://github.com/erento/eslint-plugin-erento-rules/blob/master/src/rules/injectable-order.md